# Delete the oldest files until directory size is 8 GB

Tags: linux, debian, raspbian

I have a main folder /srv/ftp with many subfolders (hundreds) and files (more than 80 000 files). This dir has 10 GB.

I need to make a script for this: I need to delete the oldest files (earliest file created) from all subdirectories until the main /srv/ftp directory size is 8GB.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script (place it inside the head folder).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo New dimension?
read dimension

initialDimension=$(du -sk | cut -f1 -d '    ') #Find initial dimension

while [ "$(du -sk | cut -f1 -d '    ')" -gt $dimension ] #While the dimension of this
#Directory is greater then $dimension (inputted before)
do
    echo Finding file
    #This let you find the oldest file name:
    uselessChars=$(find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    oldestFile=$(find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort |head -n 1)

    oldestFile=${oldestFile#$uselessChars}; #Remove useless chars
    oldestFile=${oldestFile# } #Remove useless space
    echo " Found: $(find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -n 1)" #Print complete path
    $(rm "$oldestFile") #Remove the file
    echo Removed $oldestFile #Print the result
done

#The result:
echo Done
echo Initial Dimension: $initialDimension
echo Final Dimension: $(du -sk | cut -f1 -d '   ')
```

i think this task could have been made more easier with python, but i wanted to try to write it in bash. 
Many things could have been done much better, but it works.

Comment: thank you. but it is not working. Linux returns "cut: invalid type or field list"

Comment: Does it say the line? @peter